# iCloud shows that it is full but I am 100% sure it is not

Tags: icloud, storage

My iCloud shows that storage is full. I have closed the photo Photo Stream that relates to iCloud and I've double checked the memory using on Pages, Numbers etc and there is not much in there:
[image]

Why is iCloud showing my storage as full? How do I check and/or fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Photo Stream has no impact on your iCloud storage. Additionally, iCloud storage is not just about your iCloud Drive - in addition to other data (e.g. Mail, Contacts, Notes, iCloud Photo Library, etc), your iCloud storage also includes any iOS backups you have enabled (i.e. from an iPod, iPhone and/or iPad).

If you have an iOS device, you can go to **Settings > iCloud** and check whether you have Backups enabled. While there you can also check what else is enabled.

In addition, you can also go to **Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage** and then tap on *Manage Storage* at the bottom of the iCloud list. This will give you a breakdown of your data usage.

Comment: Photo Stream doesn't even count towards iCloud storage.

Comment: D'oh! I was so busy answering the question that I totally missed the assertion from the OP's question. Thanks for keeping me honest! I've updated my answer to clarify the point. :)

Comment: No worries, I wasn’t intending for you to edit your answer — it wasn’t wrong, just wanted to add the extra detail!